# Rails Login as admin using bootstrap modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, bootstrap-modal

I've spent several days on it, but couldn't carry out. I wonder how can I make logging in as admin using a Bootstrap Modal either when clicking on a link or visiting /admin page.
I made an `admin namespace`

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :users
  resources :shops
  match '/index' => 'shops#index', :via => :get, :as => 'index'
  get '', to: 'sessions#new', as: '/'
end
```

and also Users & Shop controllers and views in `/admin` folder.

Different solutions on the web couldn't work and that's why I decided to make it from the very beginning.
Just say if any other information about application is needed. Relying on your knowledge, I will be grateful for any help!

**PS:** Authentication method in application is taken from Hartl's tutorial (there's no authentication libraries).

Login page (/admin), **views/admin/sessions/new.html.erb**:

```
<% provide(:title, "Sign in") %>
<h1>Sign in as admin</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

    <p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And also, if non-admin tries to access /admin page, he will be redirected ro the 'login as admin' page. **controllers/admin/users_controller.rb** has admin_user for show action:

```
class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: [:show, :destroy]

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Hotels Advisor!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit    
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to [:admin, @user]
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    unless current_user?(user)
      user.destroy
      flash[:success] = "User deleted."
    end
    redirect_to admin_users_url
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end

    # Before filters

    def creating_forbidden
      if signed_in?
        redirect_to root_url, notice: "You are already regsitered."
      end 
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end
end
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question completely. Would you like to be able to present a 'login-page' so that admin can login when they access /admin pages? or if I'm logged in as an admin and I access /admin pages, I would be able to access the /admin pages, however, if I'm logged in as a non-admin, I won't be able to access /admin pages. Please clarify. Also, what authentication library are you using in this application?

Comment: @andHapp, Sure! I added in PS.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. This seems to be setup correctly. Can you tell us what's not working?  Would you like to log-in someone as an admin by just clicking a link? How would you link this to work? Please clarify.

Comment: It used not to work, but now everything works fine! Thank you for your questions, andHapp, they led me to an answer! Also I wanted to login as admin through Bootstrap Modal pop-up window, but that doesn't matter now, because regular login form works. Thank you again!